# Progress bar/% in duplicity?

Tags: backup, duplicity

I'm starting to experiment with Duplicity for my backups and found that it lacks an option to show a progress bar or percentage, it just shows the files to be backup. Is there a way to get a progress bar based on total data to be uploaded/current data uploaded or something like that?

Comment: Perhaps this works for you: https://github.com/quentin/Duplicity-progress

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This functionality has (finally) been added to Duplicity since version [0.6.22](https://launchpad.net/duplicity/+milestone/0.6.22) on 2013/08/22. The feature is activated with the `--progress` [option](http://duplicity.nongnu.org/duplicity.1.html#sect6).

Answer (score 3):

### PARTIAL SOLUTION:

Progress can be monitored using the `pv` function. It's especially useful when backing up large files. It is not that useful with many small files, but allows to see progress on currently opened file and the upload speed. `pv` is not installed by default.

How to use `pv`: First grab the process id, and then put it as a parameter `to pv -d`.

---

### Example:

```
ps -ef | grep duplicity
```

We read the PID (first number after the username), then

```
pv -d PID
```

---

### Or a one-liner*:

*assuming we are copying a file that has "disk" in it's name. The second grep narrows the search results.

```
pv -d $(ps -ef | grep duplicity | grep disk | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f 2)
```

where:

`-d` tells pv to expect PID of the process to monitor,

`ps -ef` prints the list of processes running on the machine,

`grep duplicity` grabs only the lines from the process list that contain duplicity,

`grep disk` avoids the first grep  process from showing in the ps -ef results and makes sure, that we only list the particular process that we want to monitor by looking for part of the name of the copied file,

`tr -s ' '` trims multiple spaces in ps -ef output to just one, so that cut can work properly,

`cut -d ' ' -f 2` cuts only the second field from the output (our PID) and uses ' ' spaces as field separators. without the previous trim, cut wouldn't work (variable amount of spaces in ps -ef output).

[pv -d in action](https://s22.postimg.cc/wby2mcabl/stack_pv_dupli_example.png)